# Searching for entries between 2 dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with entries that have a `start_date` and `end_date` (both indexed, DATE format). I want to return a list of all entries where today is between these 2 dates. Here are 2 options I've considered:

1) Direct query:
MySQL query (where 28/02/2014 would be variable of course):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE '28/02/2014' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

2) Daily cronjob to go through all entries and update a field `is_valid` (boolean format) to be true when today is between both dates, and false otherwise (the performance is less important here as it's not customer-facing). Then the MySQL query to select entries would be:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE is_valid = 1
```

The end goal is to have the fastest query (will be used in search results which would be a prominent page of the site) when entries could reach 100,000 or even millions in the future. I'm not sure if indexing dates would be good enough, or if the cronjob is just overkill - or if there is an even better way to do this!

Thanks in advance for your advice in which option to choose!

EDIT: thanks for the replies - is this index structure good?
[image]

Comment: Save dates as int timestamp and index them...when the table grows a lot, you can made partitions based on that timestamp

Comment: If you index the dates make sure you have a covering index that contains both dates.

Comment: Your proposed indexes will only narrow things down if you have the userid and category id in the SELECT. Ie, when you run the select the index will only be used up to the point where it refers to a column whose value you do not have in the where clause. For your use this might be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the faster query between these two options, then there is nothing like a cron job to set the flag appropriately.  You should then *index* the resulting column, because otherwise you have to do a full-table scan.  Without the index, this approach is probably slower than using the dates with an index.

For most purposes, a composite index on `start_date` and `end_date` is the preferred solution and should be quite fast enough.

I suspect that you are submitting to the daemon of premature optimization.  The fastest approach is to run a cron job and load today's data into a new table, properly indexed and structured for your analysis.  Barring that, a composite index is a very reasonable approach.  Although updating a flag does solve the problem, it would be neither the fastest nor the cleanest method.

Comment: Thanks - from time to time I want to double check I haven't taken a bad habit! I'll use your suggestion of cronjob+dedicated table if it ever becomes a huge table in the future.

Comment: @Davor . . . To be honest, thinking about scalable performance is a good idea when developing an application; I don't want to be too discouraging.  I think it is similar to the misquoted aphorism "Money is the root of all evil" where the correct quote is "Love of money is the root of all evil".  That is, performance considerations are an important part of design.  Focus on premature performance is too much detail at the wrong time and place.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this same schema before. A query with the dates was fast enough, if you have the right indexes.